# Multiple data objects in a single row in ListView of Android?

Tags: android, listview

Example dataset: "A","B","C","D"

I want to show the ListView like:
`"A"  |   "B"   |   "C"`

I am not trying to show details of "A" in multiple columns..
I want to show 3 items per row, instead of 1. I don't want to use GridView.

Currently i have succeeded in doing this.

I use:

```
public int getCount() {
    if(dataSource!=null){
        return (int) Math.ceil((double)dataSource.size()/3.0f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And in the getView part, i use position*3 to get the first position of the next 3 items and i create the views accordingly (i+1,i+2). It works perfectly. Except, only some of the list is drawn.
Scrollbar is correct and it shows that i can scroll more, however before the half of the list is drawn, suddenly it doesn't draw the next half and scrollbar just touches to the bottom.

So, my division by 3 is ruining something.. If i don't divide the count by 3, all of the items are drawn but scrollbar shows 3 times more of the real height (as i am drawing 3 items in 1 row instead of 3 rows.

What am i missing here?

Comment: I do something very similar in one of my apps and don't have a problem. I would double check that `getCount()` is always returning what you expect and that `getView(...)` is always called with the expected positions. Also, in my experience, a solution like this will introduce some lag into the scrolling because you're going to be doing a lot of work to lay out the 3 items when `getView` is called.

Comment: +1 in getView function, i didn't use total count correctly, now it works. I am not using xml for the layout, i am creating them programmatically. Do you think it will still lag?

Comment: I'm also not using XML, but rather a custom `ViewGroup` subclass that aims to minimize the work done in `onMeasure` and `onLayout`, but I still get some lag.

Comment: Yes, i made it and it lags as you said.. I am reusing the views but it changes nothing.. I don't understand. There must be an explanation for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was not correctly applying number of total rows correctly in the getView() function. Now it works. Thanks to @scompt.com